# how to create a dynamic form in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view form in `codeigniter`. When I enter the computer serial number, all the values related to this computer will come on the form using json method. Now if I want to add 10 computers how do I do it in the view and insert the same in database. Can anyone suggest me a dynamic way to do this?

```
Controller function:
    public function getComputerDetails() {
            $comsno=$this->input->post('comsno');
            $this->load->model('calendarmodel');
            $result=$this->calendarmodel->getComputerDetails($comsno);
            if (isset($result)) {
                echo json_encode($result);
            }
        }

Model:

    public function getComputerDetails($comsno) {
            $this->db->where('com_sno', $comsno);
            $query = $this->db->get('computers');
            return $query->row();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

complete View:

```
      <?php include('calendar_header.php');?>

    <head>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <!--<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>C:\xampp\htdocs\CI_project\images\computers.png"  style="width: 600px">-->
     <!--<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/computers.png">-->


      <div class="container">
    <?php if($error=$this->session->flashdata('number_exists')):?>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
      <strong>Customer number</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">is</a> registered.
    </div>
    </div> 
         </div>
    <?php endif;?>


     <?php if($error=$this->session->flashdata('no_number')):?>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
           <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
      <strong>The number does not exist</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">To add a New Customer</a> click Add Customer
    </div>
    </div> 
         </div>
    <?php endif;?>

    </div>
        <?= form_open('autocomplete/store_calendar',['class'=>'form-horizontal'])?>



        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/image/computers.jpg" alt="computers">
        <div class="container">
      <div class="form group row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div align="left">


<div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-2">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customer Phone Number<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'cus_phone','id'=>'cus_phone','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'customer phone number','value'=>set_value('cus_phn')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php echo form_error('cus_phone',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
  <div class="form group row">

 <div class="col-lg-12">

  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Customer Name</a>-->
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customer Name<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'cus_name','id'=>'cus_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter your name','value'=>set_value('cus_name')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
        <?php echo form_error('cus_name',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
  <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>-->
       </div>
</div>
</div> 


</body>
<body>
  <div class="float">
    <div class="form group row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div align="left">

  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-2" >

  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Customer Name</a>-->
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Billing Address<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'cus_badr','id'=>'cus_badr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter billing address','value'=>set_value('cus_badr')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php echo form_error('cus_badr',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
  <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>-->
  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customer Ship Address<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'cus_sadr','id'=>'cus_sadr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter shipping address','value'=>set_value('cus_sadr')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
        <?php echo form_error('cus_sadr',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div> 


</body>
<body>
  <div class="float">
    <div class="form group row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div align="left">

  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-2" >

  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Customer Name</a>-->
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Computer Serial No<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'com_sno','id'=>'com_sno','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter computer seial no','value'=>set_value('com_sno')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php echo form_error('com_sno',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
  <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>-->
  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">  Computer Manufacturer  <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'com_make','id'=>'com_make','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter computer make details','value'=>set_value('com_make')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
        <?php echo form_error('com_make',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div> 


</body>
<body>
  <div class="float">
    <div class="form group row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div align="left">

  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-2" >

  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Customer Name</a>-->
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Computer Model<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'com_model','id'=>'com_model','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter computer model','value'=>set_value('com_model')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php echo form_error('com_model',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
  <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>-->
  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">  Computer Configuration  <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'com_config','id'=>'com_config','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter computer configuration','value'=>set_value('com_config')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
        <?php echo form_error('com_config',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div> 


</body>
<body>



<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Computer Hire Start Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input id="date1" type="text" class="form-control" name="training_start_date" value="">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Computer Hire End Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input id="date2" type="text" class="form-control" name="training_end_date" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <span> Diff:</span>
        <span id='diff'> - </span>
        <span> Days</span>




</body>
<body>
  <div class="float">
    <div class="form group row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div align="left">

  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-2" >

  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Customer Name</a>-->
  <fieldset class="form-group">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Hire Mode<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
   <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <?=form_input(['name'=>'hire_mode','type'=>'radio','class'=>'form-check-input','placeholder'=>'Enter computer hire mode', 'id'=>"hire", 'value'=>"0", 'checked'=>""])?>

          <!--<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">-->
          Monthly
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
           <?=form_input(['name'=>'hire_mode','type'=>'radio','class'=>'form-check-input','placeholder'=>'Enter computer hire mode', 'id'=>"hire", 'value'=>"1", 'checked'=>""])?>
          Weekly
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check disabled">
      <label class="form-check-label">
           <?=form_input(['name'=>'hire_mode','type'=>'radio','class'=>'form-check-input','placeholder'=>'Enter computer hire mode', 'id'=>"hire", 'value'=>"2", 'checked'=>""])?>
          Daily
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php echo form_error('hire_mode',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
</fieldset>
      </div>
</div>
</div>

  <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>-->
</body>
<body>
  <div class="float">
    <div class="form group row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div align="left">

  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-2" >

  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Customer Name</a>-->
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Computer Hire Rate<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?=form_input(['name'=>'mohr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter monthly hire rate','value'=>set_value('mohr')])?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php echo form_error('mohr',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
  <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>-->
</div>
</div> 


</body>
<body>
  <div class="float">
    <div class="form group row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div align="left">

  <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>-->
  <div class=" form group row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">  Computer Total Hire Rate  <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
  <?= form_input(['name'=>'tohr','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter total hire rate','value'=>set_value('dahr')])?>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
        <?php echo form_error('tohr',"<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");?>
      </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div> 


</body>
<div class="row" align="center">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
    <?= form_reset(['name'=>'reset', 'value'=>'reset','class'=>'btn btn-default'])?>
    <?= form_submit(['name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Submit','class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>
  </div>
  </div>
</html>
<script>
  $('#date1').datepicker();
            $('#date2').datepicker();

            $('#date2').change(function () {
                var diff = $('#date1').datepicker("getDate") - $('#date2').datepicker("getDate");
                $('#diff').text(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1);
                $('#diff').change();
            });

</script>
<script>
  $('#diff').change(function () {
    var hireMode = $('input[name=hire_mode]:checked').val();
    var startDate = $('#date1').val();
    var endDate = $('#date2').val();
    var mRate = $('input[name=mohr]').val();
    $.ajax({ 
           url: "<?php echo base_url();?>autocomplete/pricing", 
           method: "POST", 
           data: {
              hire_mode:hireMode, com_sdate:startDate, com_edate:endDate,
              daily_rate:dRate, weekly_rate:wRate, monthly_rate:mRate
           }, 
           success: function(res) { 
                  console.log(res);
            } 
    });
  });

  $('#cus_phone').on('input', function(){
    var phone = this.value;
    if (phone.length == 10) {
      $.ajax({ 
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>autocomplete/getUserDetails", 
        method: "POST", 
        data: {cusphone:phone}, 
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#cus_name').val(data.cus_name);
          $('#cus_badr').val(data.cus_badr);
          $('#cus_sadr').val(data.cus_sadr);
        } 
      });
    }
  });

  $('#com_sno').on('input', function() {
    var com_sno = this.value;
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>autocomplete/getComputerDetails", 
      method: "POST", 
      data: {comsno:com_sno},
      dataType:"JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#com_make').val(data.com_make);
        $('#com_model').val(data.com_model);
        $('#com_config').val(data.com_config);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var dataString = $("#FormId").serialize();
    var url="autocomplete/store_calendar"
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>autocomplete/store_calendar",
        data:dataString,
        success:function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
        });     
  })
</script>
```

Comment: it's a bit complicated to suggest a course of action without seeing full code from your view. But basically what you need is to name each set of elements as an array (ie., `computer[i]['make']` `computer[i]['model']` `computer[i]['config']` First "group" has i=0, second one has i=1 and so forth. Each time you fetch the computer details, you'd pass the `i` value to your jQuery functions, get the computer details and then update the elements with the same value for `i`.

Comment: Further explanation needed!

Comment: can somebody please help me with this?